# Unity and Container.Resolve

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a class which I need to use my container to resolve a concrete class from an interface. this class can't take a constructor, so I am trying to resolve the class using the container.Resolve method.

In my UnityHelper, I have setup all my container items, and the one in question is defined as:

```
container.RegisterType<OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, AuthorisationServerProvider>();
```

And then in my startup.cs file, I am attempting to resolve the class based on the interface:

public class Startup
{
    private OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider _authorisationServiceProvider;

```
public Startup()
{
    var _container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
    _authorisationServiceProvider = _container.Resolve<OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>();
}
```

However, I'm getting a design time error on the 'Resolve'saying that the non-generic method cannot be used with typed arguments.

I've seen places where it seems I am doing it right. Eg: [Unity Container Resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449106/unity-container-resolve)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that you have to manually add the reference to Unity. For those who get this, ensure you have:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
```

Comment: I just searched and at very first scroll the answer! why don't you mark it as answer

Comment: Because I am a fool and forgot. Thanks for the reminder. Done.